# Beyond configuration, allowing for flexibility on a per service call basis type of pattern

Tags: design-patterns

Say you have a ecommerce app, and have an API call to create an order.
OrderService.create(...);

Order creation is a complicated process, many things will happen as a result of this call:

1. shopping cart items will be used to create an order and order details
2. email sent to customer
3. inventory levels adjusted
4. billing and shipping objects created and status changes
5. etc.

Now say I only wanted to do a subset the steps from #1,2,3,4 or 5.

One approach would be a configuration setting, but that would apply to ALL OrderService.create calls regardless of who makes the call.

I want a design pattern or design that will allow me to choose what I want to happen on a PER call basis.

Is there a design pattern for this type of behaviour?  This is a new system and I want to read up on possible approaches.

Comment: Pass collection of values which will describe actions you want to be executed in given order. Then in the service class associate every value with corresponding action and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a design pattern for this type of behaviour?

There's a solution, but I doubt it has been labelled a pattern, as this is a fairly elementary problem to solve. At best, I'd call it an authorization pattern.

> I want a design pattern or design that will allow me to choose what I want to happen on a PER call basis.

The assumption here is that you want to predefine your rules, and then have the requests be treated accordingly. The only other option would be for each request to wait for manual (on the fly) user input, which doesn't sound like something you'd want.

Why am I telling you this? Well, the above conclusion proves that you need some way to format these predefined rules, in a way that your runtime can independently identify these requests and determine which rules to apply to them.

Here's where we hit a roadblock. **You didn't specify how to distinguish these requests**. "Per request" (as per your question) makes no sense. First of all, I doubt you're going to be creating an individual rule for every individual request that will be sent to your API. Secondly, you still haven't elaborated how a request will be identified. Is it by authorization token? Requester's IP address? Time of day? User account? Random dice roll?

For the sake of example now, I'm going to assume that you handle these based on the authenticated/authorized user account. How you include that information in the request (e.g. auth token) is an implementation detail that's up to you.

At a very barebones level, the data you need to describe your rules is something like this:

```
 USER     ACTIONS
===================
 Adam   |  2,3
 Ben    |  1,3,4
 Chris  |  1,2,3,4
```

I numbered the actions based on the bullet points you listed.

This data perfectly describes which actions a user is allowed to perform. This isn't the most future-proof implementation, but it actually does what you need it to do.

Further improvements to the below (barebones) examples are generally a good idea, but they depend on some design decisions you've made along the way. Since you didn't elaborate on the implementation details, neither can I.

**Where do you store this data?**

That's really up to you. There are plenty of ways to store data, each with their own benefits and drawbacks.

- Database - Great for configurability, especially if you want your users to be able to configure these rules. Somewhat of a performance bottleneck due to having to fire off a query.
- Config file - More cumbersome to configure (requires server access), requires an IO operation, but can pretty much ensure that only your developers can access this.
- Local file - same arguments as for the config file, but less obviously part of the codebase. Only an option if the config file is already too big.
- Hardcoded - This is the most performant option, but it's also the least configurable. Adjusting anything will require a redeploy. Any built version's ruleset is can be deterministically tested and won't ever change.
- ...

It's unclear how often you're expecting to configure these rules, as well as who is going to be configuring them (end user, end user admin, developers, ...). Pick the storage option that suits you.

**How do you check these rules?**

Barring the specifics of fetching the data (which, as we discussed, can be done in different ways), the logic of checking the rules is fairly straightforward. Note that I'm using C# here. You didn't specify a language, so I'll comment the code to make sure you understand its purpose.

```
// Represents a row from the rule set (see data table example)
public class Rule
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<int> AllowedActions { get; set; }
}

public class RuleChecker
{
    // Tells you if a certain user can perform a certain action
    public bool CanUserPerformAction(string userId, int actionId)
    {
        // Get rules from data storage
        List<Rule> rules = ...

        // Get the rule that matches the user ID
        var userRule = rules.SingleOrDefault(rule => rule.UserId == userId);

        // Check if such a rule exists
        if(userRule == null)
        {
            // No rule exists for user!
            return false;
        }

        // User exists, check their if allowed actions contains the requested action
        return userRule.AllowedActions.Contains(actionId);
    }
}
```

This is just a basic example. Certain improvements can be made, but they mostly depend on your implementation details, which you never elaborated on.

This rulechecker can then be used everywhere you need to check for a rule, e.g:

```
if(myRuleChecker.CanUserPerformAction(currentUser, sendEmailActionId))
{
    myMailSender.SendEmailTo(currentUser);
}
```

Again, this is just a basic example.

---

The above is a working but very barebones implementation. There are many more considerations here to improve the code, but they rely on certain decisions you make.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the logic for creating the order exists in other services, and all the `create()` method is doing is using each service (in other words, it doesn't really contain any logic on its own).

For example, adjusting inventory levels on its own has nothing to do with creating an order. You could also adjust inventory levels by restocking.

I don't think you need a design pattern here. If the steps for creating the order already exist in other services there is nothing stopping you from simply calling those other services directly. A potential change here would be to encapsulate the state of the order in an object instead of doing it one shot in `create()` that way you can control the flow, though I can't think of a good reason to do that.

Comment: Well I guess I have to pass metadata to the OrderService.create(...) call to tell it what other services should be used.

Comment: @coolbreeze You could extract that logic into a separate factory method that returns the correct service, though I'm again stuck feeling like that isn't really something you should need to do. Do you have a concrete example of a case where the service you're using depends on some metadata? Or are you being hypothetical (not asking to be rude, I'm just having trouble figuring out why it's needed)

Comment: the meta data was a way I thought I could control what happens downstream i.e. create order, but skip inventory check but include shipping calls etc.    This is not hypo but something I need for a new project :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for a policy service or workflow service? As in "Process this order under the sales tax exempt rules" or "Here are the user properties, route the order accordingly, SMB customers this way, enterprise customers that way..."